# Return from star PassPRNT to host application

Tags: printing

I was about to use Star passPRNT to print from my web site, using a Samsung S7 tablet.
I use the Chrome browser (or in fact the Star webPRNT browser which is based on Chrome)
It works well, besides that the callback from passPRNT opens a new tab in my browser instead of just going back to the previosly opened tab.

How can I make passPRNT just close and go back to my first opened tab?
This is how the URI looks:

```
passprnt_uri = "starpassprnt://v1/print/nopreview?back="encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);......
```

'window.location.href' just opens a new tab in the browser